# Typedef changing behaviour causing error and warning

Tags: c++, c, typedef, declaration

Following are few experiments over typedef modifications and I couldn't understand 2 and 6 line. Why 2 and 5 are giving different results?
Please give me some clarification.

```
typedef long _long;
extern _long tl;         //1 Fine...OK
extern _long int tli;    //2 extraneous `int' ignored...??
extern int _long til;    //3 `_long' does not name a type...OK
extern long l;           //4 Fine...OK
extern long int li;      //5 Fine...OK
extern int long il;      //6 Fine...??
```

Comment: To start with, don't use global names with leading underscores, they are reserved by the specifications.

Comment: Just a remark: `long x;`, `long int x;` and `int long x;` are all equivalent

Comment: Yeah right, I used it here just for easy reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to use `typedef`s in a way akin to a macro, but that's not how they work.

When you `typedef long _long`, the expression `_long int` doesn't expand to `long int`, it just becomes a compiler error because the `long` and the `int` become two types for the variable.

You can apply cv-qualifications to such a type, such as with:

```
extern const _long foo;
```

Or:

```
volatile _long bar;
```

And if you want something to actually be a `long int`, you can set a typedef for that:

```
typedef long int MyLongInt;
```

Also, as an aside, don't name your typedefs with a leading underscore.  The Standard reserves many names with leading underscores.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.
BTW, I used _long for clarification and yeah, it should be avoided. Thanks for advise. :)

Answer (score 4):

The `typedef` keyword creates an alias for a *complete type*, not for another keyword.

So e.g.

```
extern _long int tli;
```

is about the same as you doing

```
extern long int int tli;
```